# Acumatica: Enabling Full-Text search on Azure SQL

Tags: acumatica

We are hosting Acumatica database on Azure SQL. Faced an issue: try to search in fast search string (top of left navigation panel) got an warning that "Full-Text Entity Index must be built before using the search. Please rebuild the index and try again." and "The Full-Text Search feature is not enabled in the database. Search by a phrase or a list of keywords might not work. You can contact the database administrator to enable the feature."
Even if specify to search in Help only it returns some result but warning still exists.

Researching Acumatica ERP Configuration Wizard application I have found, that class AcumaticaDbKeeperMsSql, method getGenerateFirstScript checks if database hasFullTextCapability. And for some reason that just checks if db engine is Azure or not. And if it's Azure then according to that logic it's not Full-Text capable. That is why, fulltext catalog is not created in the Azure SQL database and Full-Text feature does not work out of the box.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. It would be better adding more details on what you have tried with specific issue.

Comment: 1. Full-Text search is not enabled locally on SQL Server 2016. Created Acumatica db. Faced a warning during search. 2. Install Full-Text, rebuilt an index through Acumatica UI. Still saw the warning. 3. Created a new db and changed connection string to the new db, rebuilt index through Acumatica UI. Now it works well. 4. Have no idea how to repeat the same on Azure SQL and do not understand why db from point #1 does not work even after Full-Text installed.

Comment: As far as I know Full-Text is enabled by default on each Azure SQL database. I did rebuild index through Acumatica UI several times. No luck.

Comment: Found in Acumatica ERP Configuration Wizard application, class AcumaticaDbKeeperMsSql, method getGenerateFirstScript check if database hasFullTextCapability. And for some reason that just checks if db engine is Azure or not. And if it's Azure then according to that logic it's not Full-Text capable. That is why, fulltext catalog is not created in the Azure SQL database. Why has it been done that way?

Comment: andy7 - I suggest you to update the question with all those findings that you detailed as comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was told, that is the know issue and will be fixed in the nearest builds.

Found steps to fix the issue manually are below:

1. Run the following scripts on Azure SQL database:

   - `CREATE FULLTEXT CATALOG [ft] WITH ACCENT_SENSITIVITY = ON AS DEFAULT`
   - `exec sp_executesql N'CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON [dbo].[SearchIndex] ([Content]) KEY INDEX [IX_SearchIndex]'`
   - `exec sp_executesql N'CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON [dbo].[WikiRevision] ([PlainText]) KEY INDEX [WikiRevision_UK2]'`
   - If you got an error that full text index already exists just drop it before run next run script above. For example, `DROP FULLTEXT INDEX ON [dbo].[WikiRevision]`.
2. Full-text catalog will rebuild automatically. Periodically run 3 SQL commands below (each 20-30 seconds). You will see that result numbers are changing. Wait until changing stops. It took about 5 minutes on my test environment.

   > `SELECT fulltextcatalogproperty('ft', 'ItemCount');`
   >
   > `SELECT fulltextcatalogproperty('ft', 'UniqueKeyCount');`
   >
   > `SELECT fulltextcatalogproperty('ft', 'IndexSize');`
3. Then restart an Acumatica instanse (through IIS, for example) to clear cache.
4. Login to the Acumatica application. Go to System -> Management -> Rebuild Full-Text Entity Index. And run PROCESS ALL. Wait until it is completed.
5. That is it. Try to search, for example, any bill number or vendor name in search string and select 'Search ... in All Entitites'.

**UPDATE 10/06/2017**

Acumatica developers provided extended version of SQL script (below) to manual fix. It even recreates system procedures `pp_EnableFullText` and `pp_DisableFullText` for some reason. Research made for Acumatica version 6.10.1219.

```
--Recreating indexes
if not exists (SELECT * FROM sys.indexes WHERE name = 'IX_SearchIndex') begin
    UPDATE dbo.SearchIndex SET IndexID = NEWID()
    CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_SearchIndex] ON [dbo].[SearchIndex] ([IndexID])
    if (SELECT count(*) from sys.fulltext_catalogs where serverproperty('isfulltextinstalled') = 1) > 0
        exec sp_executesql N'CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON [dbo].[SearchIndex] ([Content]) KEY INDEX [IX_SearchIndex]'
end
else Begin 
    if (SELECT count(*) from sys.fulltext_catalogs where serverproperty('isfulltextinstalled') = 1) > 0
        if not exists (SELECT * FROM sys.fulltext_indexes f
                        INNER JOIN sys.indexes i on f.Unique_Index_id = i.Index_id and i.object_id=f.object_id
                        Where f.object_id = object_id('SearchIndex') and i.name = 'IX_SearchIndex')
            exec sp_executesql N'CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON [dbo].[SearchIndex] ([Content]) KEY INDEX [IX_SearchIndex]'
End

if not exists (SELECT * FROM sys.indexes WHERE name = 'WikiRevision_UK2') begin
    UPDATE dbo.WikiRevision SET UID = NEWID()
    CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [WikiRevision_UK2] ON [dbo].[WikiRevision] ([UID])
    if (SELECT count(*) from sys.fulltext_catalogs where serverproperty('isfulltextinstalled') = 1) > 0
        exec sp_executesql N'CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON [dbo].[WikiRevision] ([PlainText]) KEY INDEX [WikiRevision_UK2]'
end
else Begin 
    if (SELECT count(*) from sys.fulltext_catalogs where serverproperty('isfulltextinstalled') = 1) > 0
        if not exists (SELECT * FROM sys.fulltext_indexes f
                        INNER JOIN sys.indexes i on f.Unique_Index_id = i.Index_id and i.object_id=f.object_id
                        Where f.object_id = object_id('WikiRevision') and i.name = 'WikiRevision_UK2')
             exec sp_executesql N'CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON [dbo].[WikiRevision] ([PlainText]) KEY INDEX [WikiRevision_UK2]'
End
GO


--Recreation System Procedures
if exists(select * from sys.objects where object_id = object_id('dbo.pp_EnableFullText') and objectproperty(object_id,'IsProcedure')=1)
drop proc dbo.pp_EnableFullText
go
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.pp_EnableFullText AS
if not exists (SELECT * FROM sys.indexes WHERE name = 'IX_SearchIndex') begin
    UPDATE dbo.SearchIndex SET IndexID = NEWID()
    CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_SearchIndex] ON [dbo].[SearchIndex] ([IndexID])
    if (SELECT count(*) from sys.fulltext_catalogs where serverproperty('isfulltextinstalled') = 1) > 0
        exec sp_executesql N'CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON [dbo].[SearchIndex] ([Content]) KEY INDEX [IX_SearchIndex]'
end

if not exists (SELECT * FROM sys.indexes WHERE name = 'WikiRevision_UK2') begin
    UPDATE dbo.WikiRevision SET UID = NEWID()
    CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [WikiRevision_UK2] ON [dbo].[WikiRevision] ([UID])
    if (SELECT count(*) from sys.fulltext_catalogs where serverproperty('isfulltextinstalled') = 1) > 0
        exec sp_executesql N'CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON [dbo].[WikiRevision] ([PlainText]) KEY INDEX [WikiRevision_UK2]'
end
GO

if exists(select * from sys.objects where object_id = object_id('dbo.pp_DisableFullText') and objectproperty(object_id,'IsProcedure')=1)
drop proc dbo.pp_DisableFullText
go
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.pp_DisableFullText AS
if exists(SELECT * FROM sys.fulltext_indexes fi JOIN sys.indexes i ON i.[object_id] = fi.[object_id] AND i.[name] = 'IX_SearchIndex')
    exec sp_executesql N'DROP FULLTEXT INDEX ON [dbo].[SearchIndex]'
if exists(select * from sys.indexes where name = 'IX_SearchIndex') 
    DROP INDEX [IX_SearchIndex] ON [dbo].[SearchIndex]

if exists(SELECT * FROM sys.fulltext_indexes fi JOIN sys.indexes i ON i.[object_id] = fi.[object_id] AND i.[name] = 'WikiRevision_UK2')
    exec sp_executesql N'DROP FULLTEXT INDEX ON [dbo].[WikiRevision]'
if exists(select * from sys.indexes where name = 'WikiRevision_UK2') 
    DROP INDEX [WikiRevision_UK2] ON [dbo].[WikiRevision]
GO
```